# How to set identity for a columns in destination table while importing from msaccess to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have successfully imported database from msaccess to sql server using linked servers but it doesn't set is identity prpoerty to columns in destination table.

I have written one stored procedure with setting the identity_insert on before the select * into query but it is being gotten error.

This is my procedure

```
create proc 
SP_Create(@servername nvarchar(100),
@datasr nvarchar(MAX),@table nvarchar(100),
@table1 nvarchar(100),@db nvarchar(100)) 
as begin EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = @servername, 
@provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for Jet',
@datasrc = @datasr,@provstr=''
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@servername, 
@useself = N'false',@locallogin = NULL,@rmtuser = N'Admin',
@rmtpassword = NULL declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) 
set @sql=' SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+@table1+' ON; select * into '+@table1+' from '+@servername+'...'+@table+' with (nolock) SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+@table1+' ON '
Exec(@sql) 
declare @sql1 nvarchar(MAX) set @sql1 ='EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver '+@servername+',''droplogins''' exec(@sql1)
end
```

would u pls resolve this

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: That table does not exist or you don't need permissions
Because here i have used select * into query so we can copy the table with schema

Comment: Yes, the table `<yourtablename>` in the destination database is *created* when you do the select ... into `<yourtablename>`. It should have all the fields of the source table including the ID column if any. It should not have any keys or fields where you need to specify "`set identity insert on`".

Suggestion: Can you list the top 10 rows in the source table and the top 10 rows from the created destination table in your question and specify what column has the wrong data?

Comment: I said the is identity property for a column has not set while importing from msaccess to sql. Here the data from source table to destination getting correctly.if we want to insert any data in the destination table means we need to give all columns data in the query including identity column that should be incremented automatically.That's the problem i am facing.